# How can I remove the side glass pane from a patio sliding glass door?

Tags: windows, sliding-glass-door

I just bought a pet door insert for a sliding glass door.

[image]

I'm assuming that it must be installed against the wall, but I cannot figure out how to remove the side panel of the sliding glass door.

The green arrow points to the glass pane I want to remove so I can put the Pet door against the frame where the red arrow is pointing and then put the green arrow pane back against it.

[image]

[image]

EDIT Adding requested images

[image]

[image]

Can it be done? Or is the whole thing one piece?

Comment: Can we get a close up pic of the border of the window frame?  Specifically where your red arrow is pointing.

Comment: I will take the picture when I get home tonight.

Comment: [Installation video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRLtrsYBGGU&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, but here's my suspicion based on the pics posted.  I may delete this answer after you post an updated close up pic.

Where your red arrow points - the white and black strip - I suspect that's the stop strip.  It goes all the way around the window panel and appears to lock it in place.  I suspect there's one on the outside as well.

To remove the glass, you're probably going to need to **carefully** remove this strip from the outside of the door frame.  Then the window pane itself should lift up and out from the bottom.

To re-secure your new pet door will include re-installing the stop strip.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the install of your product, whether it goes in place of the glass or the entire panel. If it goes in place of the entire panel (glass and frame), then locate any screws that are holding the panel to the track, probably in the top and bottom left of the frame when viewed from the inside.

This should let you pull the entire frame to the left a few inches. Then you grab the frame, lift up straight up so it's above the lower track, and push the bottom out towards your deck. Finally, lower the frame so it comes out of the top track and it's free.

If you're only removing the glass, then a close up photo of the glass edge will help, and Greebo's advice should be helpful.